# How to delete all folders inside folder using python?

Tags: python

Is it possible to delete all folders inside a folder without using a specific path?, Here i am moving the contents of the file then after that i want to delete if it is a dir

```
import os, zipfile
import shutil
import os
from os import path


dir_name = 'C:\\Users\\Guest\\Desktop\\OJT\\samples'
destination = 'C:\\Users\\Guest\\Desktop\\OJT\\scanner\\test'
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(destination):
    for name in files:
        filename = os.path.join(path, name)
        shutil.copy2(filename, destination)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is, Use shutil's `rmtree` method.

```
import shutil 
shutil.rmtree('directory') # the directory you want to remove
os.listdir()
```

You can also use `os.rmdir` but that won't work if there is any content in it.

If you want to check if that specific path is a directory then you can use `os.path.isdir` then run `rmtree` if that returns `TRUE`

And incase you want to keep the *root* folder intact then you could `walk` that directory and calling `rmtree` on each item.

Comment: what i mean is, how can i delete all the folders in a folder, because .rmtree removes also the root folder

Comment: You could go into the directory then loop through it's contents and running `rmtree` on all directories.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [@Vineeth Sai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52491352/how-to-delete-all-folders-inside-folder-using-python/52491393#52491393) earlier, If you want to delete all sub directories in a directory, just loop through each file with [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) and if the file is a directory, apply [`shutil.rmtree()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree):

```
from os import listdir

from os.path import abspath
from os.path import isdir
from os.path import join

from shutil import rmtree

path = 'YOUR PATH HERE'

for file in listdir(path):
    full_path = join(abspath(path), file)

    if isdir(full_path):
        rmtree(full_path)
```

The above also uses [`os.isdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) to check if a file is a directory.

Answer (score 1):

If `Vineeth's` answer is not suitable for your case, you could you `subprocess` module to run `os` specific commands like below

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('rm -rf /path/of/the/dirctory/*', shell=True)
```

The above command is `linux` specific, you could use windows counterpart of the same command above.

Note - Here `shell=True` will expand `*` into files/folders.

Also, note `Vineeth's` answer is `os` independent, and above will be `os` specific. **Be cautious**.

P.S. - You can also run `powershell` commands using `subprocess` module.